# python - json keep returning JSONDecodeError when reading from file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I want to write data to a json file. If it does not exists, I want to create that file, and write data to it. I wrote code for it, but I'm getting `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`.

Here's part of my code:

```
data = {"foo": "1"}
with open("file.json", "w+") as f:
    try:
        file_data = json.load(f)
        json.dump(data, f)
        print("got data from file:", file_data)
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
        json.dump(data, f)
        print("wrote")
```

I put print statements so that I can "track" what's going on, but If I try to run this code multiple times, I keep getting `wrote` message.

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you open the file for write/read therefore once you open the file it will be emptied.

Then you want to load the content with `json.load` and it obviously fails because the file is not a valid JSON anymore.

So I'd suggest to open the file for reading and writing separately:

```py
import json

with open("file.json") as json_file:
    file_data = json.load(json_file)
    print("got data from file:", file_data)

data = {"foo": "1"}
with open("file.json", "w") as json_file:
    json.dump(data, json_file)
```

Hope it helps!